# Getting individuals from a given data property using jena

Tags: jena, semantic-web, owl, ontology, owl-api

I'm wondering if there's a way using Apache Jena or OWL API, to retrieve ontology's individuals by a given data property, and then matching the relations between those individuals from their in common object properties.

---

EDIT: Here's a sample of the CSV file

```
,California,Texas,New York,Alabama

Hillary Clinton,69%,31%,33%,67%

Donald Trump,31%,69%,67%,33%
```

And this is a simple domain ontology created with Protégé:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#"
     xml:base="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:elections2016="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVote -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVote">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_democratic"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Votes"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVoteByClasseSociale -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVoteByClasseSociale">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVote"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_democratic"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#ClasseSociale"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVoteByPeriode -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVoteByPeriode">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVote"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_democratic"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVoteByRegion -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVoteByRegion">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVote"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_democratic"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Region"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVoteByVotingAge -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVoteByVotingAge">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HasVote"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_democratic"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#VotingAge"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#hasNomineeDemocratic -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#hasNomineeDemocratic">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Republic"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#hasNomineeRepublic -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#hasNomineeRepublic">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Democratic"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_democratic"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#hasPartone -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#hasPartone">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Political_parties"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Democratic"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#haspartytwo -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#haspartytwo">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Republic"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#age -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#age"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#asset -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#asset"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#currentLocation -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#currentLocation"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#name -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#name"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#occupation -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#occupation"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#spouse -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#spouse"/>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#ClasseSociale -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#ClasseSociale">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Votes"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Democratic -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Democratic">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Political_parties"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_democratic -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_democratic">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Democratic"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Republic"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Votes"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Political_parties -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Political_parties"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Region -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Region">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Votes"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Republic -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Republic">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Political_parties"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Votes -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Votes"/>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#VotingAge -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#VotingAge">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Votes"/>
    </owl:Class>
    


    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Alabama -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Alabama">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Region"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#April -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#April">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#August -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#August">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Between_18_and_49 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Between_18_and_49">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#VotingAge"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#December -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#December">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#DemocraticNominee -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#DemocraticNominee">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Democratic"/>
        <name>HillaryClinton</name>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#DonaldTrump -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#DonaldTrump">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_republic"/>
        <age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">70</age>
        <asset>4,500,000,000</asset>
        <currentLocation>NewYork</currentLocation>
        <occupation>Businessman</occupation>
        <occupation>MelaniaKnauss</occupation>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Etudiant -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Etudiant">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#ClasseSociale"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#February -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#February">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HillaryClinton -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#HillaryClinton">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Nominee_democratic"/>
        <currentLocation>chicago</currentLocation>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Ingenieur -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Ingenieur">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#ClasseSociale"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#January -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#January">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#July -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#July">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#June -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#June">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#March -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#March">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#May -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#May">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#New_York -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#New_York">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Region"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#November -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#November">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#October -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#October">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Over_50 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Over_50">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#VotingAge"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Professeur -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Professeur">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#ClasseSociale"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#RepublicNominee -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#RepublicNominee">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Republic"/>
        <name>Donald Trump</name>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#September -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#September">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Periode"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Texas -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Texas">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.kdm.com/OWL/elections2016#Region"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

e.g: I'd like to get the inviduals that has a data property value equals to Hillary clinton^^xsd:string and Texas^^xsd:string ,  and then matching the relations between those individuals from their object properties.

Comment: Plz provide more details of your problem, and the solutions you have try.

Comment: So I'm trying  to annotate a data table using a domain ontology, and I want to retrieve the table's cells (which they are exactly a data property assertion in my ontology) and look for the individuals they represent in my domain ontology. and then link those individuals by the obkect properties in commun.

Comment: What do you have now? A table or an OWL ontology? Or a simple RDF dataset?

Comment: Yes my input is a CSV table and an OWL domain ontology. My goal is to make a semantic RDF annotation of the table using my domain ontology. I'm not really sure about my method though . Do you think there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: Ok, but what is the question now? You need a mapping from the columns in the table to properties (or maybe classes) in the ontology. If you have that, what is the exact question? Since you've been asking about Jena and OWL API. It's often better to provide an example with sample data, i.e. a part of the table and the corresponding part of the ontology. And then what you expect as result.

Comment: I've just edited the thread, I hope this will give you better insight

Answer (score 0):

It is possible here a short previous of the 2 steps you need to make it work.

1. Push your csv file into the ontology. Using owl-api you will have to create 'propertyAssertion' for each value. Using jena, you will have to create a 'statement' for each value.
2. Add a reasoner to your ontology and transform the pattern you want to "match" into a class expression (OWLClassExpression in the owlapi).

Ask the reasoner for the individuals, properties, classes of the entities that "match" the ClassExpression.

Here a simple example of individual querying using the owlapi reasoning interface [an example](https://github.com/Galigator/openllet/blob/integration/examples/src/main/java/openllet/examples/OWLAPIExample.java):

```
OWLClassExpression expr = OWL.min(OWL.DataProperty("http://myDataProperty"), 1)
namedIndividuals = reasoner.getInstances(expr)
```

This simple example is a pattern matcher for individuals that have at least one property "http://myDataProperty".